# How to make iOS (Xcode) app available to either Canada or US users

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, publishing, countries

I have an iOS app that needs to be installed by users who have either a Canada or US based Apple ID.
The app is published to the App Store under my US Apple ID and apparently users with Canadian info (address / credit card?) can't download it unless they also create and use a US Apple ID.
Any way to publish the app so there isn't this limitation?
Is there any Apple documentation someone can point me to that details this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Any way to publish the app so there isn't this limitation?

Yes, there are App Store territories that include many if not most countries, and Canada is absolutely one of them. In general, you set the availability under the Pricing and Availability tab in App Store Connect, but you may need to take some other steps such as setting a price and perhaps adding export compliance information before you're able to change your app's availability.

Everything you need to know (and more) is detailed in [App Store Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/).

Comment: Thank you Caleb! I'll have to go into Connect and poke around. We have the distribution model for this app which allows us to issue redemption codes to specific users in order to install the app. I don't recall the name off hand but it's not B2B or enterprise.

Comment: That sounds like a custom app (formerly B2B). If so then you may also have to look at the details of the Apple Business Manager account you are using to "purchase" the app. Honestly if you are using custom apps you should really use an MDM to distribute them.

Comment: @Paulw11 We are using a Volume Pricing Plan (as best I can tell). It's free to the user but requires a Redemption Code (pre-generated by Apple). I'm not sure we could use an MDM since the users are subcontractors using BYOD. I haven't kept up with MDM but don't they, in general, require a client that basically takes 'admin' control of their device / phone?

Comment: Yes, that is custom app (formerly B2B). There is often an  companion app that lets the user enrol their device and install apps from your private "store", but it is the management profile that controls the device.  When you install an MDM profile on a BYOD device you can establish a partition that separates your corporate data from their personal data.  This enables you to erase the data and apps your organisation has placed on their device.  You can also enforce some other policies such as requiring a passcode; - https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/security/sec38eb8731b/web

Comment: Not only does MDM/EMM enrolment make it much easier to deploy VPP apps, it helps you ensure company data is secured and can be remotely removed if the device is lost or the contractor leaves.  It also helps ensure BYOD devices comply with minimum standards (passcode, minimum iOS level etc)

Comment: With user enrolment you provide the user with a managed Apple ID (email@yourcomapny.com)  that they can use alongside their personal Apple ID.  This ways apps assigned to their managed Apple ID can't be used once their contract ends and you disable their managed Apple ID. Right now you are providing a code that associates your app with their personal Apple ID.  They have access to that app forever.